# SQL Server 2014 32 bit upgrading 64 bit in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: sql-server, windows, iis

I am running **SQL Server 2014 standard** on **Windows Server 2012 R2** machine.

I installed sql server by [Install link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BRa9.png)

But i problem is the sql server is running 32 bit on my machine (14 core Xeon and 64 gb RAM) and consumes a lot cpu is very high (some times 100%) but ram 16 gb only
[image]
It is also an issue for IIS 8.5.
I suspect that 32 bit installation may cause the problem.
WHY it takes so much  CPU for Sql server and IIS?
and how to convert it to 64 bit of Sql server and IIS 8.5?

Comment: For IIS, you set the 32/64 bitness on app pool level inside IIS manager. For SQL Server, I suspect [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55030/how-to-move-from-32bit-sql-server-install-to-64bit) still stands.

Comment: High CPU ? any idea?

Comment: SELECT @@version  shows   **Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (Intel X86) 
 Feb 20 2014 19:20:46 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (WOW64) (Hypervisor)**  is 32 bit and after upgraded **Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
 Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offcourse you need to install a 64 bit instance of SQL Server. I think you made a mistake by downloading the 32 bit version of SQL Server?

I think the biggest problem with SQL Server 32 bit is that SQL Server can only allocate 2GB of memory. So the rest of the 14GB isn't used at all by SQL Server. In many cases this will cause a lot more disk reads because the database buffer cache can't hold a lot of pages in memory.

My first suggestion is to install a new instance of SQL Server (64 bit) and migrate these databases. It's not certain you're CPU "problem" (50/60 avg isn't really a problem) is gone after this upgrade. But this will be a big step.

Comment: You know, given that his SQL Server is using extremely little memory - and that he has supposedly 100% cpu, indicating NO WAIING FOR IO - I am more inclined to say some seriously bad programming is eating all the CPU. The type where you have non-matching field types or something. If memory would be an issue, SQL Server would wait for disc IO, resulting in low CPU.

Comment: I think you don't have enough information to say there is no waiting for IO. He is only telling CPU avg 50/60% sometimes up to 100. The first step in this situation is a installation of a 64 bit engine.

Comment: using 100 cpu must not be normal .As RAM 64 gb cpu is high compared to CPU usage

Comment: I didnt say 100 cpu usage is normal. I said 50/60 average can be normal and shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: **a lot more disk reads.........** solve my question.As no more than 2 GB is used ,i causes more i/o by CPU which is high for production server. so i am migrating sql server to 64 bit. But 32 bit and  64 bit ships with same .iso(DISK). so i installed it to `x64` folder,start **LandingPage.exe** ,showed my path to install media `x64` and installed successfully 64 bit version of SQL SERVER 2014 STANDARD. To my surprise,SQL SERVER 2014 enterprise does not cause this issues install 64 bit by `DEFAULT` setup

Comment: No. Disc reads stall the CPU - if disc IO is high, then be definition CPU is low because the CPU is busy waiting for the discs to finish. WHich does NOT show as busy in the task manager. Generally SQL Server CPU usage - unless incompetent programming or some VERY special cases are involved - is VERY hard to get to a high CPU usage.

Comment: I don't think this is right. CPU can get high when disk IO problems are there. CPU needs to be active for all these sessions so this can result in CPU pressure even when you really have a disk bottleneck. I really had some cases where CPU pressure was high and a INDEX solved high CPU pressure. Maybe I will setup a test-case in the nearby future to proove it.